# What is <%= in jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, pug

I am going through a tutorial that uses html for its view engine, I am working on jade and just wanted to know what this would become in a jade page.

```
<%=firstName%>
```

I tried this but it tells me that the everything inside the brackets are undefined, even though the userTemplate id is being called in the main.js file.

```
script(src='/js/main.js', type='text/javascript')
script(id='userTemplate', type='text/template')
        #{firstName}#{lastName}#{email}#{phone}#{birthday}#{city}
```

Comment: `<%=firstName%>` is ERB style, isn't it?

Comment: What is ERB style, and this actually works I had a spacing issue, so I had to keep it all 
  <%=firstName%><%=lastName%><%=email%><%=phone%><%=birthday%><%=city%>  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<%=` is for a javascript template mostly likely Underscore. The problem is Jade is interpreting your javascript template as Jade. I believe you just need to add a `|` to the beginning of the line and Jade will directly output that line without interpreting it.

```
script(id='userTemplate', type='text/template')
    | <%= firstName %> <%= lastName %>
```

Alternatively I believe you can add a `.` after the script line and it does the same thing.

```
script(id='userTemplate', type='text/template').
    <%= firstName %> <%= lastName %>
```

Check out the [documentation under Tag Text](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a6-3) for more information about it.